# Programming Dell Tape Drive with C#

Tags: c#, storage

Has anyone got experience in writing files to tape drives. i'm writing some tar files from a c# windows service to a dell powervault 124t. 
I was hoping there was an API or some tool I could use (pay for potentially).

I had a look at symanntecs open netbackup api but not sure it that is the correct route.

Answer (score 4):

That's my job :-), except that I use C and not C#.

But there's a API in the Visual C.

Here's some functions: 
CreateFile() & CloseHandle()

ReadFile  && WriteFile

PrepareTape ()

GetTapeParameters ()

GetTapePosition() &&  SetTapePosition()

DeviceIoControl()

WriteTapemark()

GetLastError()

Looks on msdn.com for help on how to use the functions.

Hope that helps...